# How to access maven dependecy from GitHub Package Registry (Beta)

Tags: maven, github, github-ci

I uploaded a maven artefact to the [GitHub Package Registry (Beta)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-github-package-registry) and want to add it as maven dependency. I'm already in the [Regestry-Beta](https://github.com/features/package-registry/signup) and activated it for my sample [HalloMaven](https://github.com/TobseF/HelloMaven) project. Also the `mvn deploy` was succesful, so the artifact is **public** available here:
https://github.com/TobseF/HelloMaven/packages
But how to include it as a maven dependency?

I tried to add it in a fresh sample project with this `pom.xml`:

```xml
<groupId>de.tfr.test</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-repo-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>github</id>
        <name>GitHub TobseF Apache Maven Packages</name>
        <url>https://github.com/TobseF/HelloMaven/packages</url>
        <!-- also tried:
        <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/HelloMaven/</url> -->
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>github.tobsef</groupId>
        <artifactId>hello-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But the dependency cannot be resolved.
It's strange that the `artifactId` is `github.tobsef.hello-maven`, which doesn't match the `hello-maven` specified in the pom. But I have no clue why the `github.tobsef` gets prepended and if the repository url is correct.

The official GitHub [Configuring Apache Maven for use with GitHub Package Registry](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-package-registry) only shows how to push it with credentials. But my repo is public, authentication is not needed.

Setup for the *HalloMaven* example:

`settings.xml`

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>github</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>github</id>
                    <name>GitHub TobseF Apache Maven Packages</name>
                    <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/TobseF</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>${env.GITHUB_USERNAME}</username>
            <password>${env.GITHUB_TOKEN}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
```

`pom.xml`

```
   <groupId>github.tobsef</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>GitHub TobseF Apache Maven Packages</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/TobseF/HelloMaven</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

`deploy.yml`

```
name: Maven Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
      - name: Maven build
        run: mvn --file pom.xml package

  deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 11
    - name: Deploy to Github Package Registry
      env:
        GITHUB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_USERNAME }}
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: mvn --settings settings.xml --file pom.xml deploy
```

The result is a `Could not find artifact github.tobsef:hello-maven:pom:1.2.1 in github (https://github.com/TobseF/HelloMaven/packages)`.

Any Idea how to setup the deployment to deploy the correct artifact and how to add it as dependency?

Comment: your artefact can be found via search: https://github.com/search?l=&q=hello-maven&type=RegistryPackages - so far so good. The artifact it shows is: 
`
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.tobsef</groupId>
  <artifactId>github.tobsef.hello-maven</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
` 
which is a different artifactId than what you seem to use. It also seems the settings.xml repo url is correct, the one you use in the pom does not match the documentation you linked.

Comment: > which is a different artifactId than what you seem to use.
Yes, but also when I try to add this artifactId, i doesn't work.
> he one you use in the pom does not match the documentation
The dependency `artifactId`  I used in the sample project, match with the deployed artifact path. Only the `artifactId` inside the deployed jar doesn't match - which shouldn't prevent it from downloading?

Comment: The artifactId listed in github.com/TobseF/HelloMaven/packages/39042 now matches. Whithout any change... mabye an error on GitHubs side (Beta product).
So now the only question is how to include it as dependency?

Comment: well those repos are not browseable somehow. So try and error. Are you sure its a public repo? Behind: https://maven.pkg.github.com/TobseF/github/tobsef I get 401 errors requiring a login. Something like https://maven.pkg.github.com/TobseF/github/tobsef/hello-maven/1.2.2/hello-maven-1.2.2.jar should be correct. But well authentication required, can't check that.

Comment: Have you tried testing your deploy locally with `publishToMavenLocal` command?

Answer (score 28):

OK ✅, I found out how to configure it the right way.

You can see a sample project with the working [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) CI and the [GitHub Package Registry](https://github.com/features/package-registry) here:
 [HelloMaven](https://github.com/TobseF/HelloMaven)
To see how the dependency can be included check the:
 [GitHub-plugin-registry-example Template](https://github.com/TobseF/github-plugin-registry-example)

The trick was to add an authentification to the GitHub API in the global maven `settings.xml`.

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>github</id>
        <username>YOUR_USERNAME</username>
        <password>YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Replace the `YOUR_USERNAME` with your GitHub login name.
Replace the `YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN` with a generated GitHub personal access token:
*GitHub* > *Settings* > *Developer Settings* > *Personal access tokens* > *Generate new token*:
The token needs at least the `read:packages` scope.
Otherwise you will get a `Not authorized` exception.

It wasn't clear that this auth is also needed to read a package. Especially because the jar is available without any login on the package page:
https://github.com/TobseF/HelloMaven/packages

So it's a little bit nasty because we have to add the `<server><id>github</id>...` and hope others will also provide the the `repository` with the `github` id. Otherwise we have to add a server config for every github dependency.

Keep in mind that every GitHub repo is its own maven repo. So there is no global registry like the maven central. Every dependency has to provide its own `repository` link declaration.

But in combination with the GitHub Actions CI, it's a very nice alternative without any third party plugins.

Comment: Until today, July 11th, 2020, there is no option for using GitHub Packages without authorization. So in other words, it's not possible to use anonymous access with GitHub Packages. You can follow the discussion in the GitHub forum: https://github.community/t/download-from-github-package-registry-without-authentication/14407/10

Comment: @FelipeDesiderati Friendly suggestion: I think you mean _even_ today, not _until_ today.  But thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: Another tip: Don't blindly dump auth keys into what is very likely a version controlled settings file. Pull them in from environment variables.

Comment: You can also use the authentication that Github has built in:
`username = System.getenv("GITHUB_ACTOR")`
`password = System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")`

Comment: FYI packagecloud.io has a free tier for publishing packages that can be accessed anonymously. I'm experimenting with them after finding out this unfortunate restriction.

Comment: Sune 2020 update: packagecloud.io. does NOT have a free tier.

Comment: aug 2023 update: still no better resource in the whole internet showing how to publish packages to gh package registry and use it in github CI. outstanding