# Is it possible to expose (Read) a maven.pkg.github.com repository without using server credentials?

Tags: maven, github

Maybe a dummy question: I have some Maven Artifacts on my maven.pkg.github.com repository and I would like to expose them, just for reading, without configuring the server credentials on settings.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just answering my own question: until today, July 11th, 2020, there is no option for using GitHub Packages without authorization. So in other words, it's not possible to use anonymous access with GitHub Packages. You can follow the discussion in the GitHub forum: https://github.community/t/download-from-github-package-registry-without-authentication/14407/10

Possible correlated: [How to access maven dependecy from GitHub Package Registry (Beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58438367/how-to-access-maven-dependecy-from-github-package-registry-beta)