# mvn deploy in Github actions gives 401 Unauthorized

Tags: github-actions

I've had several attempts at deploying an artifact to https://maven.pkg.github.com from `.github/workflows` but they all result in a 401 Unauthorised error.

```
      - name: Setup java for mvn deploy
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 8

      - name: Deploy kaldi-linux.zip
        working-directory: kaldi
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        run: |
          cp ../.github/kaldi/* .
          perl -pi -e 's/^(\s{4}<version>).*(<\/version>)/${1}$ENV{"KALDI_VERSION"}${2}/g' pom.xml
          mvn deploy
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy)
 on project kaldi: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.kaldi:kaldi:pom:da93074
 from/to temp (https://maven.pkg.github.com/nalbion/vosk-api): Transfer failed for 
https://maven.pkg.github.com/nalbion/vosk-api/org/kaldi/kaldi/da93074/kaldi-da93074.pom 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

logs here: https://github.com/nalbion/vosk-api/runs/683615393?check_suite_focus=true

My understanding is that `actions/setup-java` is supposed to provide `settings.xml` and environment variables and the deployment should be straight forward. Is there something that needs to be done that I'm not doing?

Answer (score 9):

I can tell you by first hand experience that it is not easy to deploy packages to github's maven repos. Forget the "simple" step shown in the packages section, the process is more involved than that. However, it is still possible to do it.

For starters, you will need a settings.xml file. Here is my minimal setup:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Authorization</name>
            <value>Bearer <GITHUB_TOKEN_GOES HERE></value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

I guess the `java` action overwrites the settings.xml, but the above is required. Another option is to use the username/password approach, but that method is quickly becoming antiquated in favour of bearer token as I did above.

Now to deploy a snapshot release with sources, this is the command I had to use:

```
mvn clean source:jar deploy -DuniqueVersion=false -Dmaven.source.useDefaultManifestFile=true -Dmaven.source.includePom=true -Dmaven.install.skip=true -DdeplyAtEnd=true -DaltDeploymentRepository='github::default::https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY'
```

Assuming you had the following in your `pom.xml` according to the [publishing guide](https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages#publishing-a-package):

```
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
     <id>github</id>
     <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
     <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

You can change the command to just:

```
mvn clean source:jar deploy -DuniqueVersion=false -Dmaven.source.useDefaultManifestFile=true -DdeplyAtEnd=true -Dmaven.source.includePom=true -Dmaven.install.skip=true
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently you need to provide credentials to download an artifact from an open source repo!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58438367/how-to-access-maven-dependecy-from-github-package-registry-beta

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is using the maven-settings-action (https://github.com/s4u/maven-settings-action):

This action also overwrites the settings.xml and therefore needs the following configuration:

```
- uses: s4u/maven-settings-action@v2.5.0
        with:
          servers: '[
          {"id": "github","configuration": {"httpHeaders": {"property": {"name": "Authorization","value": "Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"}}}}]'
```