# 401 with GitHub packages and Maven

Tags: maven, github-package-registry

I have a problem with GitHub packages and dependencies.
I published SNAPSHOTs for few packages in GitHub packages, and I'm trying to use them when building artifacts but with no luck.
I always get 401 unauthorized from Maven when trying to reach it.
So, settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.2.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>./mavenRepo</localRepository>
    <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
    <offline>false</offline>

    <pluginGroups>
    </pluginGroups>
    <proxies>
    </proxies>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>ArturJarosz</username>
            <password>MAVEN_GITHUB_TOKEN</password>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Authorization</name>
                        <value>Bearer MAVEN_GITHUB_TOKEN</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>

    </servers>
    <mirrors>

        <mirror>
            <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
            <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
            <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
            <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>
            <blocked>true</blocked>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>github</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>github</id>
                    <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/ArturJarosz/Task</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

As you can see I have tried both ways of authorizing server that I have found.
According to the documentation, username and password should be enough: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry

Also other people seems to be successful with that approach: [How to access maven dependecy from GitHub Package Registry (Beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58438367/how-to-access-maven-dependecy-from-github-package-registry-beta)

Header path was added after reading that one, I assumed it will not hurt: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/49836#discussioncomment-5413387

I replaced token here of course, but let's assume that is hardcoded here (I tried injecting from env as well).
When I check that token with curl:

```
curl -sS -f -I -H "Authorization: token MAVEN_GITHUB_TOKEN" https://api.github.com | grep -i x-oauth-scopes
```

I get:
delete:packages, write:packages
And I assume that scope of the token is sufficient, as under write is read as well.

But when trying to resolve it using Maven:

```
#13 2.865 [DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.arturjarosz:task-parent:0.6.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/task-schema/./mavenRepo)
#13 3.302 [DEBUG] Using transporter HttpTransporter with priority 5.0 for https://maven.pkg.github.com/ArturJarosz/Task
#13 3.302 [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://maven.pkg.github.com/ArturJarosz/Task with username=ArturJarosz, password=***
#13 3.306 Downloading from github: https://maven.pkg.github.com/ArturJarosz/Task/com/arturjarosz/task-parent/0.6.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
#13 4.242 [DEBUG] Writing tracking file '/task-schema/./mavenRepo/com/arturjarosz/task-parent/0.6.1-SNAPSHOT/resolver-status.properties'
#13 4.254 [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.arturjarosz:task-parent:0.6.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/ArturJarosz/Task): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
#13 4.258 org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata com.arturjarosz:task-parent:0.6.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/ArturJarosz/Task): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
```

I am able to download that POM/related JAR with curl by hand with that token. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?
I will appreciate any help.

EDIT:
Seems like I was wrong with token. Scope was not sufficient, and it required also metadata scope. With new token everything works as expected.